# Encrypting home folder in Debian

Tags: linux, security, encryption

Is it possible to encrypt home folders of users in a Linux system (say Debian) in such a way that root cannot see their content?

Comment: if you encrypt home, then features that use files found there, like IMAP ans SSH services will not work.

Comment: @Jasen that is one use case I had in mind, to have user mail stored in their home directory and only accessible to themselves. Can't an IMAP daemon decrypt the user's pass-phrase with their password, for instance, and then mount the directory?

Comment: yes, imapd could be modified to do that, but the MDA needs write access when new mail arrives.  I guess you spool new mail in /var/spool/mail and have imapd fetch it from there when the user logs in.

Comment: The chosen answer isn't satisfactory... But indeed appears to be the reality. I am still pondering about ways to offer degrees of protection to user data when a server gets compromised.

Comment: In case someone else stumbles here, this is a related question: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5017/ssh-to-decrypt-encrypted-lvm-during-headless-server-boot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing is preventing root from subverting the services the user is interacting with to steal their keys when they are next used.

So,any solution is at best temporary.

Comment: So basically this means encrypting the home directory or not makes no difference?

Comment: yeah, it's basically impossible to stop root from doing something that a user can do. eg: root can access the memory used by any process, even the kernel.  the key will be there somewhere.

Comment: Ok, I see your point. What if we lower the requirements? (a) What would be a good way to encrypt your home folder so other (non-root) users can't  see the contents?  (b) How can we ensure that someone with physical access to the server but without root password cannot access them?

Comment: `cryptfs` under `fuse`:  http://thesimplecomputer.info/encrypt-your-linux-home-folder-2-ways-and-10-steps

Comment: @Jasen, thanks... But can't a person with access to the server -- such as the hosting company -- get around cryptfs under fuse? (1) user313114 raised  looking into memory  -- which a VPS-host can also do. (2) And if the machine is booted into single-user-mode, they will become root.  (I assume the decryption phrase is saved somewhere for the boot loader to use; if not, how can the server restart?)

Comment: if you have physical access getting root is easy. and you can't block root.